# Using tags in StatsD/InfluxDB: can't get query that shows total value across tags

Tags: tags, influxdb, grafana, statsd, telegraf

I am new to Grafana/InfluxDB/Telegraf/StatsD. I have succesfully integrated StatsD library that sends to Telegraf/InfluxDB, and can graph this data in Grafana.

So far so good.

However, I am running into a weird problem when I enable tags in the StatsD calls. I can't get the graph to correctly show the total requests / minute across all tags by just omitting the WHERE clause. I would expect that not selecting a tag in the WHERE clause, would return all the data for that statistic. But the graphs show that this is not the case. I would expect that the 'all' graph would always be having higher values then the 'tag1' graph.

What am I missing here?

[image: before and after adding tags]
[image: queries]

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data looks like in [line protocol](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/). Just at the surface, I think you might want to use `non_negative_derivative(sum())` without any tags specified, instead of `non_negative_derivative(mean())`

Comment: When using nnd(sum), I get only the sum as first value in the graph, and then the remainder is 0. So it doesn't seem to group the sum by time.

Comment: line protocol is something like: a.b.c.d,tag1=value,tag2=value:1|c.

Comment: What does ` I get only the sum as first value in the graph, and then the remainder is 0` mean? I'm not sure I follow.